# Bittrex Api: Conditional Fills, Fill-Or-Kill etc.

Tags: api

I need to adjust the bittrex api for a client:

the LIMIT_BUY or LIMIT_SELL (and CANCEL) orders work so far.
But he got a problem with Partial Fills. The api doc. on their website doesn't mention these options, which in the web interface exist.

So we were wondering if someone knows if these options ( as described here: https://support.bittrex.com/hc/en-us/articles/202227464-What-is-Time-in-Force- ) 
may be available for Orders via the bittrex api.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these orders are available. The partial fills you are experiencing can be the result of not enough liquidity in the best available bid / ask price. An immediate or cancel order will either fill the order or cancel it in the same request.

If you are still having trouble, there are alternatives to using the Bittrex API. You could try using the Shrimpy Developers API. They connect to exchanges and handle all the complexities so you don't need to. You can find information about their APIs here: https://developers.shrimpy.io/